# Goo Dictionary: What does it mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, etymology, dictionary, resources

I’m sure you guys are well aware of the Japanese dictionary Goo.

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/

Why is it called “Goo”? Even in romaji, Goo sounds unusual. I doubt it refers to the English meaning of the word. I did some research on google and as far as I can tell, it’s not a company either.

Is it an acronym for something? I’d really like to know.

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goo

Comment: It’s all in Japanese, it’d take me ages to understand with my current level...

Comment: The answer to your question is highlighted in bold in the first paragraph. **goo** is not a Japanese-language term.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goo), *goo* is supposedly an abbreviation for

> 「**g**lobal network が無限大（**∞**）に拡大し続ける」

i.e. "**g**lobal network continues to expand infinitely" (infinity sign is represented by **oo**)